# Pandas groupby and count: Include categories that are not in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame with Feature (1-4) and some names. Not all features are actually present in the DataFrame (3 is missing):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        [[1, 'name_1'],
         [2, 'name_2'],
         [2, 'name_3'],
         [4, 'name_4'],
        ],
        columns=[
            "Feature",
            "Name",
        ],
    )
#   Feature Name
#0  1   name_1
#1  2   name_2
#2  2   name_3
#3  4   name_4
```

I want to groupby Feature and count:

```
df.groupby("Feature").count()
#   Name
#Feature    
#1  1
#2  2
#4  1
```

As expected, feature 3 is not included in the count output.

Question: Is there a pythonic way of getting to the following output?

```
#   Name
#Feature    
#1  1
#2  2
#3  0
#4  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by all possible values in `range`:

```
r = range(df['Feature'].min(), df['Feature'].max() + 1)
print (df.groupby("Feature").count().reindex(r, fill_value=0))
         Name
Feature      
1           1
2           2
3           0
4           1
```

Or is possible create `Categorical` column, so `count` create `0` for values from `range` not exist in column, see also [categorical operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#operations):

```
r = range(df['Feature'].min(), df['Feature'].max() + 1)
df['Feature'] = pd.Categorical(df['Feature'], categories=r)
print (df.groupby("Feature").count())
         Name
Feature      
1           1
2           2
3           0
4           1
```